# Get parent component properties on click of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm not sure if this is the right way to going about my problem, so I'm open to other methods as well.

When I click on a child component (Image), I want to be able to get access the properties of the parent component. Here is my code so far:

**Parent Component**

```
import {Image, Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import localForage from 'localforage';
import Activity from './activity';


testClick(e){
    console.log("click handled", e.target.getAttribute('value'));
}

render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={4} smPush={4}>
                    <h2 className="center-header">Explore Ibiza</h2>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row />
                <Activity handleClick={(e)=>{this.testClick(e)}} description="Dining" imageSource="https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/95971965.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200" />
                <Activity description="Diving" imageSource="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/8d/1f/6a/linda-playa.jpg"/>
                <Activity onClick={this.handleClick} description="Boating" imageSource="https://lvs.luxury/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1.jpg"/>
            <Row />
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
  return(
<Col sm={4}>
  <p>{props.description}</p>
  <Image onClick={props.handleClick} value={props.description}  src={props.imageSource}className="activity-image margin-bottom-5"/>
</Col>
```

)

**Explanation**

I'm currently able to get the value, but if what if I want to get the `description` property of the parent element as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but I think that you just need to pass an extra parameter to the parent's callback/handler.

Maybe something like this may help:

```js
<Image onClick={e => this.props.handleClick(e, props.description)} ...
```

Comment: Yes, you were on the right track. Will update with my solution!

Comment: @AustinWrenn While there is a lot of debate on precisely what part of another user's code is acceptable to edit, in general you should just post a *comment* suggesting the code change and let the OP do the edit. The clear exceptions are code indentation/formatting edits (except for languages like Python where indentations are integral to the language), typos/miss-spellings in comments, and possibly typos in printed strings. Any other changes run the risk of breaking code, changing the intent of the author, or even accidentally fixing the error integral to a question…

Comment: @AustinWrenn I have edited the answer to demonstrate what other types of edits are acceptable. Also, don't forget to accept one of the answers if it solves the problem, and upvote any answers that were useful.

Comment: @AustinWrenn If you are planning on updating with your solution ***please*** don't modify the code in your question. Either append a section titled **EDIT:** to the question, or, especially if the update is substantive, add your own answer.

Comment: @robinCTS Thanks for the comments. Sorry, pretty new to this!

Comment: @AustinWrenn No problem. I forgot to mention above, when you *do* edit a post, make sure you fix *all* the typos, grammar errors, bad formatting and any other issues you can find, just like the ones I fixed in this answer. Note, however, that the edit I did here would be classified as a "trivial" ***suggested*** edit. (As a 2000+ rep user my edits are not "suggestions" anymore but are automatically applied.) The reason such minor *suggested* edits are frowned upon is that they unnecessarily take up multiple reviewers' time.

Comment: Nichola - Just a tip for your benefit. Back ticks are meant to be used to format inline code segments, variable names, etc. You also only need one before, and one after, the text to be formatted. (Using three is redundant.) For one line of code on a separate line, like in this case, you *could* use back ticks, but then you wouldn't get the benefit of the syntax highlighting that you would get from using the proper code block formatting.